# C++11 random library in Android JNI

Tags: android, c++, c++11

I am trying to compile an Android app with a native component that uses the C++ `random` library.

My `Application.mk` file is:

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=gnu++11
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
```

On compilation I get the error:

```
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: Project <= main.cpp
/home/user/project/main.cpp:12:18: fatal error: random: No such file or directory
#include <random>
```

Is the `random` library available for Android?

Comment: Now open in the AOSP bug tracker: [Issue 216331: STLport does not support C++11](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216331).

Answer (score 1):

> APP_STL := stlport_static
>
> APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=gnu++11
>
> NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8

You're building agains STLPort - which as far as I can tell - is a C++03 standard library implementation.  Hence it won't have C++11 headers.

Of the other [options](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html), you might consider:

```
APP_STL:= gnustl_static
```

or

```
APP_STL:= c++_static
```

Which give you GNU libstd++ or LLVM's libc++ respectively.  If you are concerned about GPL polution to your app (as Google clearly are not using libstd++ by default), use libc++.  You might as well you clang as the compiler as well at this point.

Comment: I have APP_STL:= gnustl_static but still get this error. Any idea what else might cause this?